# Not able to get output in html svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am working on a project where i need to create resizable rectangles on my image.
I found this codepen useful:
https://codepen.io/taye/pen/xEJeo

the problem is when i write same code in my codepen, its not working same. see 
here 
https://codepen.io/KushalParikh/pen/rJOeOy.

Can you please tell me what I am missing. I am new to javascript and svg.
my code

```js
var svgCanvas = document.querySelector('svg'),
    svgNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
    rectangles = [];
  
function Rectangle (x, y, w, h, svgCanvas) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
  this.stroke = 5;
  this.el = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'rect');
  
  this.el.setAttribute('data-index', rectangles.length);
  this.el.setAttribute('class', 'edit-rectangle');
  rectangles.push(this);

  this.draw();
  svgCanvas.appendChild(this.el);
}

Rectangle.prototype.draw = function () {
  this.el.setAttribute('x', this.x + this.stroke / 2);
  this.el.setAttribute('y', this.y + this.stroke / 2);
  this.el.setAttribute('width' , this.w - this.stroke);
  this.el.setAttribute('height', this.h - this.stroke);
  this.el.setAttribute('stroke-width', this.stroke);
}

interact('.edit-rectangle')
  // change how interact gets the
  // dimensions of '.edit-rectangle' elements
  .rectChecker(function (element) {
    // find the Rectangle object that the element belongs to
    var rectangle = rectangles[element.getAttribute('data-index')];

    // return a suitable object for interact.js
    return {
      left  : rectangle.x,
      top   : rectangle.y,
      right : rectangle.x + rectangle.w,
      bottom: rectangle.y + rectangle.h
    };
  })
  .inertia({
    // don't jump to the resume location
    // https://github.com/taye/interact.js/issues/13
    zeroResumeDelta: true
  })
  .restrict({
    // restrict to a parent element that matches this CSS selector
    drag: 'svg',
    // only restrict before ending the drag
    endOnly: true,
    // consider the element's dimensions when restricting
    elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
  })
  .draggable({
    max: Infinity,
    onmove: function (event) {
      var rectangle = rectangles[event.target.getAttribute('data-index')];

      rectangle.x += event.dx;
      rectangle.y += event.dy;
      rectangle.draw();
    }
  })
  .resizable({
    max: Infinity,
    onmove: function (event) {
      var rectangle = rectangles[event.target.getAttribute('data-index')];

      rectangle.w = Math.max(rectangle.w + event.dx, 10);
      rectangle.h = Math.max(rectangle.h + event.dy, 10);
      rectangle.draw();
    }
  });

interact.maxInteractions(Infinity);

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  new Rectangle(50 + 100 * i, 80, 80, 80, svgCanvas);
}
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: #2e9;
  
  -ms-touch-action: none;
      touch-action: none;
}
.edit-rectangle {
  fill: #92e;
  stroke: black;
}
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<svg>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed your pen is not working properly. You forgot to add interact.js to your pen as necessary javascript resource. Just go to `Settings|Javascript` and add something like `https://c4d6f7d727e094887e93-4ea74b676357550bd514a6a5b344c625.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/interact-1.1.1.min.js`

Answer (score 1):

You need to import

https://c4d6f7d727e094887e93-4ea74b676357550bd514a6a5b344c625.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/interact-1.1.1.min.js

in your JS